# Add new rows to dataframe populating one column with a string and another with values from 2nd dataframe column in R

Tags: r, row, addition, data-wrangling

I have the following string and 2 dataframes. There are many sets of this configuration (components, fueltypes, etc). I will create one set as an example. If components, fueltypes, etc has no data then I want to fill them as shown below.

Doing this operation is contingent on components, etc not having any data rows.

```
rocketnum <- "0000"
events_components <- data.frame(unique_event=c("thrust","azimuth","gyro","spin"))

#create empty df with column names but no data
components <- data.frame(rocketnum=character(),
                 event=character(),
                 powerlevel=character(),
                 propellant=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

events_components:

[image]

components:

[image]

and want the following as a result in components:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do not misunderstand the question, then you want to populate the `components` table using `rocketnum` and `events_components`, if `components` is empty. This could be done by using

```
if (nrow(components) == 0) {
    
    # extend the empty data frame by the needed number of rows
    components[1:nrow(events_components), ] <- NA
    
    components$rocketnum <- rocketnum
    
    components$event <- events_components$unique_event
}

components

  rocketnum   event powerlevel propellant
1      0000  thrust       <NA>       <NA>
2      0000 azimuth       <NA>       <NA>
3      0000    gyro       <NA>       <NA>
4      0000    spin       <NA>       <NA>
```